# How to run selenium test scripts in android browser

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver

How to run selenium test scripts in android browser 
I am getting an error message stating

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. Build info: version: '2.32.0', revision: '6c40c18', time: '2013-04-09 17:22:56'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_07'
```

as a prerequisites, I have successfully installed webDriver APK

```
adb -s 4df7e035582e21e3 forward tcp:8080 tcp:8080
```

but while running my test scripts it throws the above mentioned error "Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure"

Can any one help me out

Please

Thanks

Comment: Information seems not sufficient... Please share the code.

Comment: Is the webdriver application opened by default in the concerned emulator / phone ??